# Control Edit Properties of JTable in Jython

Tags: swing, jython

How would I be able to set certain columns of a JTable to be editable/not editable in Jython?

My table:

```
self.table_data = []
data_model = DefaultTableModel(self.table_data, self.colnames)
self.table = JTable(data_model)

self.table_pane = JScrollPane()
self.table_pane.setPreferredSize(Dimension(480,370))
self.table_pane.getViewport().setView(self.table)
```

Comment: https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/editable-jtable-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Jython by extending the isCellEditable method of the DefaultTableModel class:

```
from javax.swing.table import DefaultTableModel
class CustomTableModel(DefaultTableModel):
    def isCellEditable(self, row, column):
        # Make column with index 1 (second column) uneditable
        if column == 1:
            return False
        return True
data_model = CustomTableModel(self.table_data, self.colnames)
self.table.setModel(data_model)
```

In this example, all columns would editable except the second column (index 1), and of course, the isCellEdited logic can be refined for any specific cell or column. Just use `if` and `elif` statements to set conditions that return `True` if the cell is to be editable or `False` if the cell is to be not editable. Finally, set a default return of either `True` or `False` if none of the conditions are met.